# My mom is driving me crazy. :-) [Probability distributions]

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Please I need serius help, with this prob. I do several problem from the book but I'm not be able to solve this:

1) My mom, mix 5000 of chocolate chips in a dove.

2) She cooked the dove and make 1000 cookies.

3) She put 20 from the 1000 cookies in a box.

Question: How much is the probability of that 10 cookies in a box, have at least 4 chocolate chips?

**I thought:**

X: random discrete variable of # chocolate chips
The problem ask: P(X>4)

and, I know also 5000Cn1000 I belive the different ways to put chocolat chips in 1000 cokies and after that she put 20 in a box, then 1000Cn20 and the question is other 10Cn4. I know for the big factorial I will use strigling aproximation.
Also I have the table of all the distributions, but I'm not able to put all my thougth together. Please , I need help. Thanks

---

Thanks, Conrad.

---

Progress:

X: # OF CHOC. CHIPS IN A COOKIE
X Poisson (lamda=5)

Then, P(x>=4)=1-[P(X=3)+P(X=2)+P(X=1)+P(X=0)]
             =1-[0.1403+0.0842+0.0336+6.737 .10^-3]
             =0.7351

---

Then 20 of this cookies are puting in a box, and I pick 10.

Let Y= number of cookies with at least 4 chocolate chips.

Then, Y->Binomial(10, p=0.7351)

Then I want to know P(Y=10)=20Cn10 p^10 (1-p)^10

Is all this procces correct?

Comment: The number of choc chips in a cookie may be approximated as a Poisson random variable with mean 5. Using this you can calculate the probability that any one cookie has 4 or more choc chips, call that $p_4$. Then, assuming the number of choc chips in the cookies are near enough independent, the probability that all 20 have four or more is $(p_4)^{20}$.